# Cannot open camera for the button click

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I wanted to open the camera using button click.
I've used `GestureDetector` and `InkWell` as well. but it's not working.

```
 Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Color(0xff201b51),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: isOk
                    ? ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          openCamera(context);

                          print("tapped");
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Tap",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

This if I use the `openCamera` without using Button click it's working. but I want to open it using button click

```
 Widget openCamera(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: VisibilityDetector(
            key: Key("unique key"),
            onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
              if (info.visibleFraction == 0) {
              } else {
                _scaned = false;
                _controller.startCamera(onScan);
              }
            },
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: QrReaderView(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120,
                  callback: (container) {
                    this._controller = container;
                    _controller.startCamera(onScan);
                  },
                )),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: the code you showing is not working?

Comment: @JohnJoe nope.  Not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this widget [camera: ^0.10.0](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)